# Nowhere dense covering number of a connected $T_2$ space

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

This is a generalization of an [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275424/dense-and-co-dense-subsets-in-connected-t-2-spaces).

If $(X,\tau)$ is a connected $T_2$ space with more than 1 point, we define its *nowhere dense covering number* $\nu(X)$ by the smallest cardinality that a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $X$ into [nowhere dense subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set) of $X$ can have. (The [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275424/dense-and-co-dense-subsets-in-connected-t-2-spaces) can be reformulated as asking whether there are connected Hausdorff spaces $X$ with $\nu(X) > 2$; the answer is [yes](https://mathoverflow.net/a/275433/8628).)

**Question.** If $\kappa > 2$ is a cardinal, is there a connected Hausdorff space $(X,\tau)$ such that $\nu(X) = \kappa$?

Comment: This is just a remark: if instead of nowhere dense sets we consider coverings by meager sets, we obtain the classical covering number of $X$, usually written as Cov$(X)$. But you are probably aware of that.

Comment: What about $\ \kappa=2\ $ ?

Comment: I don't think your older question is asking what you claim it is. **Any** space has $v(X)>2$.

Comment: (@RamirodelaVega, I was joking. Sorry. PS. Ok, Taras has answered the question fully in his comment to this question and to the follow up question).

Comment: @MathieuBaillif Note that $v(X)=cov(X)$ except for meager spaces where $v(X)=\aleph_0$ and $Cov(X)=1$.

Comment: Haha, of course. When I wrote my remark I somehow forgot that the union of two nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense.