# "Coloring" the ideals of a ring

Tags: graph-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, graph-colorings

Let $R$ be a ring with more than 1 element, and let $A$ be a non-empty set. We call a map $c:R\to A$ an *ideal coloring* if for every nonempty ideal $I$ with $I\neq\{0\}$ the restriction $c|_I$ is not constant (that is, the elements of every nontrivial ideal receive at least 2 "colors").

Is there a ring that can be colored with $3$ colors, but not with $2$ colors?

Comment: Your example doesn't work, the function $c$ is constant on $2\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Isn't $c_{(2)}$ constant? How about the $2$-coloring of $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $c(n) = 0$ if $n$ is a square, $1$ otherwise.

Comment: Right sorry will remove the example!

Comment: I'm curious where this definition came from. Could you sketch the motivation? Would it possibly be interesting to consider colorings of the nonzero elements of the ring?

Comment: I was trying to see whether something like this was being done on rings: https://dominiczypen.wordpress.com/2017/07/17/coloring-connected-hausdorff-spaces/ The question asked in the post was asked here but has not been answered: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275489/nowhere-dense-covering-number-of-a-connected-t-2-space Your suggestion of the nonzero elements might be interesting!

Comment: @ZachTeitler I think the modified version of my question that you are suggesting is very interesting. Do you want to ask it? If you don't, I can do it.

Comment: Please go ahead! :-) I'm afraid I don't have time to think through what the "right" question is. (If we're coloring nonzero elements and want the coloring to be nonconstant on the nonzero elements of ideals, then suddenly we are ignoring ideals with only one nonzero element, such as $(m) \subset \mathbb{Z}/2m\mathbb{Z}$; I'm not sure if the question is still interesting at that point... maybe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ring can be ideal-colored with $2$ colors. Let $0$ be colored by $0$, and every other element by $1$.

Comment: How foolish of me not to see this answer...! I apologize and thank you for writing it up.

Comment: Oh, well, you're welcome. It was a coin toss, to write it here or in a comment.